# Laravel: Trying to detect a range of hex colors

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to refrain from using a library to do this but I am sending a method a hex color as a string and I'd like to determine if it's a white (or near white) color and if so throw an exception.

```
$color = $request->input('color') // '#FFFFFF'
```

doing so for white ( like above ), or any single color, would be pretty self explanatory but I can't figure out how to map out a bunch of light colors without explicitly creating an array with every light color

Comment: Not for nothing, but the comment in your code has `// '#000000'` which is black, not white (which would be `#FFFFFF`).

Comment: correcting @WesleySmith, thanks

Comment: https://24ways.org/2010/calculating-color-contrast/ you can also check via color contrast towards white.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably 100 ways to do what you are asking, this is the first that came to mind.

```
$color = "#FAFBFE";
$numVal = hexdec(substr($color, 1));

$red = ($numVal & 0xFF0000) >> 16;
$green = ($numVal & 0xFF00) >> 8;
$blue = $numVal & 0xFF;

if ($red >= 225 && $green >= 225 && $blue >= 225) {
   // Close enough
}
```